# Installing SDK iOS

Tags: ios, sdk

i am going to install the iOS SDK on my MAC and i just want to ask what should the SDK version respect to run on my MAC ?? THX in advance.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

You should always install the latest production (i.e.: not beta) version of Xcode/the iOS SDK supported by your hardware/operating system, the main reason being that you can always release software targeted against an earlier iOS version.

i.e.: You don't need to keep multiple versions of the SDK installed just so you can create software for an older iOS release, you simply change the release target as required within your project's build settings.